# I cannot reach the script editor

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to insert a script in a Google sheet file. Choosing tools, script editor reaches in an error page: "File cannot currently be opened.
Check the address and try again."

With annother account in the same GSuite domain there are no problems.

I tried: Tools, script editor
With my other account: no problems.
With the second accound: error message

(no code)

I expected a new tab with the script editor.

Comment: It seems to be a rights issue. I have created the file with account A and shared it with account B. With A it works, with B not.

Comment: are you the owner of the file?  is the file on a shared drive or team drive?

Comment: I cannot replicate this problem and haven't found any other case with your same error message, please create a case in Issue Tracker with the Apps Script component so Google can take a look: [1] https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/ [2] https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui